# Clearing only values from an object on click of a function by keeping the keys in polymer 3

Tags: polymer-3.x

I am getting the keys of an object from an API response like this

```
"subscriptionDetails":
    [
        {
            "subscriptionKey":"Mobile Number",
            "dataType":"NUMERIC",
            "isMandatory":"M",
            "length":8
        }
    ]
```

keys can be more than one. I have entered some value for mobile number. On click of a button i want to clear the value which i have entered by keeping the keys. I tried few things like below but none worked. Kindly help.

```
this.set("subscriptionDetails.subscriptionValue", undefined);
    this.set("subscriptionValue", undefined);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object contains an array in which objects are stored, hence the [ and the {.
Therefor `subscriptionDetails.subscriptionValue` wont work since you need to reference the array first like:

```
subscriptionDetails[0].subscriptionValue
```

Furthermore your data contains no 'subscriptionValue' but seems to contain a 'subscriptionKey'

Comment: Hi Thomas, subscriptionValue will be sent on click of proceed. Key and value is set like below. After getting key, value pair, i will be sending it in the API body.
var consumerCodeDetails = [];
    _.forEach(this.subscriptionDetails, function (consumerCode) {
     var tempObj = {
      "consumerCodeKey": consumerCode.subscriptionKey,
      "consumerCodeValue": consumerCode.subscriptionValue
     }
     consumerCodeDetails.push(tempObj)
    })